# Need a simple, good (fairly priced) ER Tool

Tags: database-design

I've been using ERWin for about 10 years now. My version is ancient and I do not think it's worth paying the ridiculous upgrade price!

Problem is it's starting to show its age - I've been using it primarliy for MS SQL.

I wish I could justify Embarcadero's ER/Studio, but I just need something that will allow me to design a DB and sync it.

I've checked out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674911/light-weight-er-diagram-tool, but nothing fits except Schemabank. But a web based tool has too many drawbacks (recurring fees, less integrated, off-site storage of data).

I've also used SQL Maestro for regular queries and DB management. It was OK, but has a few definite shortcomings. Has anybody used the ER designer successfully?

What do you guys use?

Answer (score 1):

We just use Visual Studio Database Edition (which is now included in the Team System Developer Edition).

The possibility to create diagrams in SQL Server as well as linking ER diagrams in Visio.

We currently use ORM tools so the documentation diagrams are the ORM diagrams in some cases.

In short, 10 years ago we used and could defend the extra cost of a purpose built ER tool. Now we just use what is build into the other tools that we use.

Comment: I've tried to use VS before for ER, it worked to a degree but it had a frustrating interface and you get the feel this is actualy a drawing tool bent to make work as a DB tool. That was 2000, I'll try the new version, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try Netbeans, its free and open source. http://www.netbeans.org/

Instructions on ER diagrams and SQL databases http://wiki.netbeans.org/ERDRequirementsV2

And instructions on connecting to MSSQL http://wiki.netbeans.org/AccessMssql

Comment: I've used Netbeans for Java Development, but it's a major development environment. I did not realise it had an ER designer. I preferably need something small and simple, installing NetBeans for the ER tool would be like buying a car for the cigarette lighter :)

I'll give it a go nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

I quite like the Quest [Toad Data Modeler](http://www.quest.com/Toad-Data-Modeler/) - so far it seems quite capable, but it's a fraction of the cost of what other "professional grade" ER tools normally cost.

Check it out! I'd say it's worth a good look for sure.

Comment: There's no pricing on the web site, only request quote which starts a process of asking questions - what did it cost?

Comment: yeah, that's annoying, I know - I was quoted for 435 Euros in Europe for a single license.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [DB designer](http://fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/) -- freebie for MySQL.

Comment: Oops, you said MS SQL; Toad should be ~$450.